# Можно ли как-то ускорить функцию setValue в Selenide?

Tags: selenium, автоматизация

Имеется рандомно-генерируемая строка из 1000+ символов. Я произвожу заполнение определенного поля на сайте этой строкой, с помощью стандартной функции.

```
textField.setValue(text)
```

Где "text" и есть та самая строка. И происходит имитация ввода пользователем, при которой скорость заполнения этого поля меня крайне не устраивает.
Есть ли возможность ускорить стандартный процесс ввода текста в поле, без использования буфера обмена?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно!
Ровно для этого был придуман режим "fastSetValue":

```
Configuration.fastSetValue = true;
```

http://selenide.org/javadoc/current/com/codeborne/selenide/Configuration.html#fastSetValue